# Regex matching anything inside brackets, supporting escaped brackets: (text), (\)text\))

Tags: .net, regex

I'm trying to come up with a regex that can validate and parse content inside brackets, supporting escaping the brackets

Examples:

**Correct**

```
(text) => 'text'
(1, 2, 3) => '1, 2, 3'
(one\(\\\@) => 'one\(\\\@'  - still ok, all three '(', '\', '@' are escaped
(!"£$%^&*) => '!"£$%^&*' special characters are ok and don't need to be escaped
```

**Incorrect**

```
(text - missing closing bracket
(text\) - missing closing bracket
\(text) - missing opening bracket
(text)) - too many closing brackets
((text) - too many opening brackets
(text)text) - too many closing brackets
```

Preferably for .Net

**Disclaimer**

I've spent considerable time and effort trying to solve this, none of which has worked, and I'd thought not to post them here to avoid misleading you. I believe solving this is best done from scratch.

E.g. ^(([^()]*))$ matches everything inside brackets, but does not support '()' brackets inside.

Help please
Stefan

Comment: This site is not a coding service. We can help you finding problems in your code, if you show it.

Comment: How would it help showing my failed attempts with not-working regular expressions? It would just confuse people, trying to fix something that's wrongly designed in the first place. I've defined my problem in the best possible way for someone with good knowledge of regex to solve, without additional bloat that's ultimately meaningless in effort to solve this problem.

Comment: Why is the `\@` not matched from `(one\(\\\@)`? Is there a limit to bracket nesting?

Comment: Bracket nesting is not allowed, any nested brackets should be rejected (fail to match). Only commented out brackets '\\)' '\\(' are allowed inside

Comment: What about the `@`? Why `(one\(\\\@) => 'one\(\\'` and not `(one\(\\\@) => 'one\(\\\@`?

Comment: Sorry I must have missed that, corrected. There should be nothing special about \@

Comment: Is the entire input the bracketed target, or can the target appear within other input, eg should input of `"foo (target) bar”` find `"target"`?

Comment: Yes I've simplified the task, the full description is actually foo1(bar) foo2(bar2) foo3(bar3). I have something that can do foo(...), however I'm struggling with the escaped brackets inside

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?!\\)\((.*)(?<!\\)\)$
```

This regular expression leverages both a negative lookahead and a negative look behind to ensure that the last two incorrect examples do not match (i.e. `(text\)` and `\(text)`).

See a full breakdown of the regex here: https://regex101.com/r/TmON1U/2

[image]

Comment: Great start, unfortunately I've missed some incorrect use cases for which this does not work (updated the original request), namely when there are multiple un-escaped opening or closing brackets https://regex101.com/r/TmON1U/3